# .NET QueryPerformanceCounter printing the day time

Tags: c#, time

I need to format the day time using QueryPerformanceCounter Win32 API. 
The format, is: HH:mm:ss.ffffff , containing hours minuts seconds and microseconds.
I need to use THIS function, because another process (written in C) is using this function and the purpose is using the same function in both places.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use :
1) The System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch class uses QueryPerformanceCounter(), saves you from having to P/Invoke it.
2) Can use directly by importing from the Win32 dll . [DLLImport(Win32)] and the name ofthe function

Answer (score 5):

The System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch class uses QueryPerformanceCounter(), saves you from having to P/Invoke it.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `QueryPerformanceCounter` to determine time of day. It can only be used to determine an elapsed interval with a very high resolution as it returns the number of ticks that passed since the computer was last restarted.

As such, at best, you may only determine how many hours, minutes, and seconds have passed since a previous reading of `QueryPerformanceCounter` which must not have happened *too long* in the past.

In order to convert from ticks to seconds you need to determine the frequency (using [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644905%28VS.85%29.aspx)) of the  ticks on the computer you're running the `QueryPerformanceCounter` function and then divide your reading by that frequency:

```
// obtain frequency
long freq;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(freq);

// then obtain your first reading
long start_count;
long end_count;
QueryPerformanceCounter(start_count)

// .. do some work

// obatin your second reading
QueryPerformanceCounter(end_count);

// calculate time elapsed
long milliseconds_elapsed = (long)(((double)(end_count - start_count) / freq) * 1000);

// from here on you can format milliseconds_elapsed any way you need to
```

An alternative to the above example would be to use the [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zz841zbz.aspx) structure available in .Net which has a constructor that takes ticks like so:

```
// then obtain your first reading
long start_count;
long end_count;
QueryPerformanceCounter(start_count)

// .. do some work

// obatin your second reading
QueryPerformanceCounter(end_count);

TimeSpan time_elapsed = new TimeSpan(end_count - start_count);

Console.WriteLine("Time Elapsed: " + time_elapsed.ToString());
```

Comment: -1 Does not answer the question at all. OP stated that he *has to* use that function. For some other reason, I have exactly the same problem. I measure intervals since ages using the method you've described, but that has absolutely nothing to do with OP's (and my) question/problem.

Comment: (+1) Undid my -1 as also everyone else apparently understood the question different from what I did. See my answer on how I understood it and what my solution was.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly I misunderstand the question, as for me none of the previous answers are relevant at all.

I had the problem (which sent me here): *Given a value from `QueryPerformanceCounter`, because something out of my control specifies timestamps using that function, how can I convert these values to a normal date / time?*

I figured that `QueryPerformanceCounter` returns the number of seconds since the system booted, multiplied (and extended in resolution) depending on `QueryPerformanceFrequency`.
Thus, the most simple solution is to get the current date/time, subtract the amount of seconds returned by `QueryPerformanceCounter/QueryPerformanceFrequency`, and then add the values you like to format as time of day.